# Error | String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server

When executing the line of code below in sql server, I receive the error message:

> String or binary data would be truncated.

What is the cause of this?

Line of code:

```
INSERT INTO ticket 
VALUES (6417, '29 Lame Street St. James', '04/17/2013', '04/25/2013', '05/01/2013', '04/25/2013', 'Expired License',121892053,128,100,121180);
```

**UPDATE**

Below is the code for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE ticket
(Ticket_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
location VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
issue_datetime DATE NOT NULL,
due_datetime DATE NOT NULL, 
court_datetime DATE NOT NULL,
paid_datetime DATE NOT NULL, 
description VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
TRN int,
offense_id int,
parish_code int,
chassis_num int,
constraint fk_ticket foreign key (TRN) references driver(TRN), 
constraint fk_tickt foreign key (Offense_id) references Offense(Offense_id),
constraint fk_tiket foreign key (parish_code) references parish(pcode), 
constraint fk_ticet foreign key (chassis_num) references Cars(chassis_num)
);
```

Comment: One of your data exceeds the column's maximum number of characters.

Comment: One of the values you are inserting is too large for the field in your ticket table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column `location` has a limit of `20`. The data you're trying to insert has a `length` of `24`.

```
SELECT LEN('29 Lame Street St. James')
```

You might want to increase the limit for the `location` column.

```
ALTER TABLE [ticket] ALTER COLUMN [location] VARCHAR(255)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well we also need table information to know which field causes it but this essentially means that one field of your table does not have enough space for one of your insert strings.

If you paste your table info we can tell you which one it is.